# Dynamic names for CSS classes with nth-child

Tags: html, css

I want to create CSS-classes for the alignments of columns of tables.

I can achieve this by explicitly defining each class. Here is a complete working example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table.s1l td:nth-child(1), table.s2l td:nth-child(2) {
                text-align: left;
            }
            table.s1c td:nth-child(1), table.s2c td:nth-child(2) {
                text-align: center;
            }
            table.s1r td:nth-child(1), table.s2r td:nth-child(2) {
                text-align: right;
            }
            table.s5l td:nth-child(5) {
                text-align: left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="s1c s2r">
            <tr>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>right</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center;" class="s5l">
            <tr>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>column for comments comment (aligned left)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Here is a comment</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the first table, for each column one class was asigned. In the second table all columns are centered, except the last one. Therefor the class `s5l` was used.

All this is part of a wiki, where users can define their tables and assign classes to the tables. Therefor it is unpredictable, which alignments for which columns are nessessary. So with this method, I am forced to define all classes explicitly for all the potential columns.

Is it possibile to create those class names implicitly instead of defining the classes for a high number of potential columns?

I want to propose this to an existing CSS-file, where no scripting is allowed, so only pure CSS may be used.

In the end it should look like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style> # However the solution looks like
            table.s[N]l td:nth-child([N]) {
                text-align: left;
            }
            table.s[N]c td:nth-child([N]) {
                text-align: center;
            }
            table.s[N]r td:nth-child([N]) {
                text-align: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="s1c s2r">
            <tr>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>right</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="text-align: center;" class="s5l">
            <tr>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>center</td>
                <td>column for comments comment (aligned left)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Here is a comment</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the classes `s1c`, `s2r` and `s5l` are created dynamically. And if, on another Wikipage, a user adds a big table with 11 columns and wants the last one centered, he simply adds the class `s11c` and it should work.

Comment: Please can you give an example of another table and which columns would need the relevant style. I don't understand which columns in a "high number of potential columns" example would be aligned left.

Comment: If it's unpredictable, I guess CSS can't predict it for you, and so you can't define rules to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.tab td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: left;
}
.tab td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}
.tab td:nth-child(3) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this won’t work for me, since I need those classes for multiple tables, were the colums are aligned differently.

Comment: you can do so by adding `.tab` class in other table as well, i guess. If i misinterpret the question. please correct me.

Comment: This only works, if the other tables are aligned the same way like the first one. If I want a table with first row centered and second row right aligned, I need new classes.

Comment: for that, you need to use `SASS` styling. It compiles on run time and you also able to pass variable to it.

Comment: A I understand, thank you, but this is unfortunatly not possible.

Comment: Something in the line.    @for $i from 1 through 39 {
  .tables{$i}l td:nth-child({$i}) { text-align: left; }
}